# Have object with texture, import and there is no texture on object

Tags: import

I'm trying to do some Minecraft animation, so I get some textures and rigs and did this.

[Picture no.1 obj with texture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twinq.jpg)
[image]

But when I import that object I´ve got this

[Picture no.2 imported picture without texture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twinq.jpg)

I'm little bit newbie and I want to join to Blender community.

Comment: Both links point to the same image

Comment: OH no, i see.
Will Edit, but shortly - IT gets that model but it looks white (without texture (imagine these Wings but only White)).
Its .obj file

Comment: Oh sorry for that Duarte. Right picture is -  https://imgur.com/Ft3cvVk <-